# Creating a library in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

Can I create a library in Angular version 5? And if I do, is it safe to assume that it will remain compatible with future versions?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but can you tell me any valid reason why you would create a library in Angular 5 instead of Angular 10?

Answer (score 1):

The Library feature in angular only appears [after Angular 6](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/2c10cf80f66e6ca3338cf50f89bf2e61be931c03/docs/documentation/stories/create-library.md).